# Grouping results of query by Time in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a table with columns [Account_No, Transaction_Amount, Transaction_Date and Transaction_Time]. I want to select accounts where "sum of transaction amount exceeded 2,000,000/- and transaction time within 10 minutes" in a day. What will be the query for this. Please help.
I am using Teradata.

Regards

Khawar

Comment: Can you and more details? What does *transaction time is between one to 10 minutes* mean, within a 10 minute period or within the first ten minutes of an hour/day?

Comment: This would be "Within a 10 Minute Period" Sir.

Comment: Any 10 minute period?  As in from 14:03 to 14:13? Or do you mean 14:00 - 14:09, 14:10 - 14:19, etc?  How do you define the start of your 10 minutes?

Comment: My idea for that is to check the sum of transactions in a day and if the sum is greater than 2M then check their transaction time and if the time range of first transaction to last transaction is 10 minutes or less then show them. This is the I just don't know the syntax for this. I hope now I made my self clear.

Comment: What about 10 minutes interval that crosses midnight?  E.g. 2017-02-26 23:57:30 to 2017-02-27 00:07:30

Answer (score 1):

One way is a self-join (as Teradata doesn't implement the `RANGE OVER` syntax) like this:

```
SELECT t1.Account_No,
   t1.Transaction_Date,
   t1.Transaction_Time, 
   Sum(t2.Transaction_Amount) AS sumamt
FROM tab AS t1
JOIN tab AS t2
  ON t1.Account_No = t2.Account_No
 -- same day within the next ten minutes of a transaction
 AND t2.Transaction_Date = t1.Transaction_Date
 AND t2.Transaction_Time BETWEEN t1.Transaction_Time
                             AND t1.Transaction_Time + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
GROUP BY 1,2,3
HAVING sumamt >= 2000000 -- more than 2 mio
QUALIFY 
   Row_Number() -- only one row per account/day
   Over (PARTITION BY t1.Account_No, t1.Transaction_Date
         ORDER BY t1.Transaction_Time) = 1
```

Comment: Hi, @dnoeth, sorry for delayed response as on weekends i don't have access of Teradata so i had to wait for start of week to check. Your suggested query worked and i got the results. However there was one problem i.e. "The query was doubling the results" e.g. If there were two actual transactions query was showing 4. So I simplified the query to single tale and it worked. However thanks for your valuable time and response. Best regards.